# How to split .wav file into two or more parts using c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, file-upload

I want to split a .wav file to multiple parts and store it as objects and send those parts to server and if any of the part haven't send to server.Only that part should resend to server using C#.net. How can I achieve this? If possible, share a detailed code snippet or other some useful link.

Comment: So what specifically are you having an issue with?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/66a2b03a-494a-4d4e-8723-902214a82b53/divide-a-wav-file-into-two-parts?forum=vbgeneral